# how to print_r in codeigniter rest controller as we see output in postman

Tags: rest, codeigniter, debugging, postman

I want to print_r my array in codeigniter rest controller. As we are seeing output of rest controller in POSTMAN, not in browser. How to debug array?

Comment: simply print_r($var) your array and run the code on postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `die` tag.

```
print_r($data);
die;
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Should be die() and only if you want no execution whatsoever afterwards.

Comment: Than you can use `exit()` function.